# Getting old data after reinstallation of my app in android

Tags: android

I am making an app where I am fetching data from a remote database and displaying it on google map. After the installation login page appears and after the credentials are verified google map appears with data fetched from database. I have saved login status and data in shared preference so that when user opens the app again after closing it it will not ask for login until user log out and also it will not ask for data until refresh button is clicked. On clicking refresh button I clear old data from preference and again save fresh data to it.
Now the problem is that whenever I uninstall and install app again I am not getting the login page and I am getting google map page with some old data.
Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: When you uninstall your app, all of its internal data is deleted. If you want to keep that data, just reinstall without uninstalling.

Comment: @MikeM. I know that when we uninstall app its internal data is deleted and i dont want to keep it also but some how when I uninstall and install app I am getting old data. I think shared preference is some how not deleted as I am not getting login page.

Comment: Oh, I get you now. I misunderstood what your question was saying.

Comment: @Henry you are right. It's all because of backup enabled in android manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may rarely face issue in older than Marshmallow version but you may face this issue in Marshmallow version because in Marshmallow all the app data are backed up. So first thing you need to set allowBackup as false in manifest as default is true so if you don't mention below code it will take it as true by default.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    ..
>
```

Then search for a folder in internal as well as external memory with the name as your app package name and delete it and restart your phone.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen, when backup for the application is enabled in the manifest.

You can specify

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    ...  >
```

to disable this.

Comment: After this we need to search and delete any folder with name as app package name and restart phone before installing app.